# How to detect collisions using Box2D in C++

Tags: c++, collision-detection, box2d

I'm learning how to use box2d but I don't understand how collisions work at all. Can someone give an in depth explanation on how they work. I've looked at the documentation for contact listeners but I only vaguely understand them and have no idea how to actually use them.

Answer (score 2):

The idea is that you can implement your own listener by inheriting from [b2ContactListener](http://www.linuxuser.at/elements/doc/box2d/classb2_contact_listener.htm). Like this:

```
class MyListener : public b2ContactListener {
    virtual void Add (b2ContactPoint *point);
    virtual void Persist (b2ContactPoint *point);
    virtual void Remove (b2ContactPoint *point);
    virtual void Result (b2ContactPoint *point);
};
```

MyListener has to define these functions. To start, you can just have them print some debug text.
You then tell Box2D that you want to use this listener, like this:

```
MyListener listener;
yourB2World->SetContactListener(&listener);
```

Now, listener will get a callback for every collision, with all the info about it in the [b2ContactPoint](http://www.linuxuser.at/elements/doc/box2d/structb2_contact_point.htm).